# How to open Context.MODE_PRIVATE files with external apps

Tags: android, outputstream

I have a string (called comments) that contains some text that I want to display using an external app. I initially create the file like so:

```
String end = "rtf";
FileOutputStream outputStream;
try {
    outputStream = openFileOutput("document." + end, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outputStream.write(comments.getBytes());
    outputStream.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However I am unable to open the file with an external application when I try the following:

```
    String type = "text/rtf";
    Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/document." + end);
    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.setDataAndType(fileUri,type);
    startActivityForResult(intent, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

The message that I receive when I open try to the document with the external app is: 
"open failed: EACCESS (Permission denied)."

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> However I am unable to open the file with an external application when I try the following:

Correct. `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` is for use with a `ContentProvider`, not for bare `file://` `Uri` values, such as you are using. [Use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to add such a `ContentProvider` to your app. See also [the "Sharing Files" training module](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) and [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider).

Bear in mind that there's a good chance that your next problem will be an `ActivityNotFoundException`, as relatively few Android devices will have an app that will support the `text/rtf` MIME type.